# How to use form_validation library rules for AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

One of my forms uses AJAX to send data. Since my page never reloads because of AJAX, is there a way I can still make use of `form_validation` to validate and output which fields are wrong? The url my form sends to using jquery is `contact/ajax_send`.

The entire AJAX works fine except I haven't inserted any validation yet.

Comment: see if this helps - its not 100% what you want - but might point you in the right direction: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/182764/

Comment: That's a very interesting thread you have there. Let's see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method, thanks in part to Jordan's answer. This returns an array containing the names of the fields which have errors.

```
// library/MY_Form_validation.php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function get_field_data(){
        return count($this->_field_data) ? $this->_field_data : FALSE;
    }

}

// Controller file
$field_data = $this->form_validation->get_field_data();
foreach($field_data as $key=>$val){
    if($key == '__proto__') break;
    foreach($val as $k=>$v){
        if($k == 'error' && !empty($v)) $errors[] = $key;
    }
}
$return = array('success'=>FALSE, 'errors'=>$errors);
```

The above code checks the `error` key whether it's empty or not. Empty values mean that it passed the CI validation while none empty values would contain the string you see when you use `validation_errors()`. Since I'm after those fields which have errors, I only needed to see which values are *not* empty disregardig those which are.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax to send the data, what you can do is, simply add the form_validation code calls before inserting into the database.

If there are any validation errors, you can either return the error messages as json response to the front end to display the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

The form validation library assigns all errors that occurred to a private array called `_error_array`, but does not expose it or provide documentation on it (notice the first underscore?). Just return a json encoded object of the errors in the controller:

`echo json_encode($this->form_validation->_error_array);`

---

If you wish, you can extend CodeIgniter's form validation library, perhaps returning `FALSE` instead of an empty array... or whatever you see fit:

```
/* libraries/MY_Form_validation.php */
<?php
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{   
     function __construct($config = array())
     {
          parent::__construct($config);
     }

    function error_array()
    {
        if (count($this->_error_array) === 0) return FALSE;
        else return $this->_error_array;
    }
}
```

Now, drop the initial underscore in the controller:

`echo json_encode($this->form_validation->error_array);`

Then decode and display errors on the client.